# Linux distro with pure HTML interface

Tags: linux, javascript

I'm looking for an existing linux distro with a pure HTML(5) client interface. Sort of like [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall), but then featuring all functionality a modern OS includes, implemented in HTML/Javascript/CSS. Kind of a [Skylight](http://www.skylightproject.com/CONTENT-392-JavaScript%20OS) clone, but then using only free and OSS software.

Inspired by [Eben Moglen's ‘Freedom in the Cloud’](http://www.isoc-ny.org/?p=1338) speech, I wonder what current implementations are available.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right, [SymphonyOS](http://www.symphonyos.com/index.html) does follow such an idea.

Quote from the site:

> SymphonyOS began as an experiment both in new user interface ideas and the merging of web technologies and the desktop. Over the five years since the SymphonyOS project made it's first public release many of the ideas we put forth have found their way into major desktop environments of all kinds. Now it is time for Symphony to take the next step and again tread where the bleeding edge of technology now allows us to venture. In looking forward we see the internet becoming the operating platform of the next decade. The differences between Desktop operating systems are dropping away as interoperability and shared services break down the barriers between platforms once and for all. Our desktops, laptops, tablets and mobile phones have become little more than a window to the online world where we create share and communicate.

Comment: Thanks! The project seems kinda dead though. Empty forum, empty wiki, (pre-alpha) release from early 2008, 4 webpages...

Comment: @user45971: Actually that page is new, I was looking at it a year ago or so, and at that point it seemed dead...but that page is new. There also people checking the forum. Feel free to ask there about the status of the project.

Comment: It's completely empty... waste of time.

Comment: @Fosco: That's the reason why I said he should ask there about the status...just because there's no one in the Forum doesn't mean that it's dead.

Comment: There isn't one post on the forum.  This just doesn't fit the request of an 'existing' distribution?  Maybe there isn't one.

Comment: @Fosco: Maybe they're using a Mailing-List, IRC, Jabber or direct mail communication?

Comment: @Bobby: maybe you're clinging to this a little too strongly?

Comment: I asked in the forum. My message even did not appear, so the forum is probably no even setup correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's no full-fledged, installable Linux distro for what you're looking for (which I assume is an installable cloud computer), [eyeOS](http://eyeos.org/) comes the closest, followed by [Tonido](http://tonido.com/) and [GoPC](http://www.gopc.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Hey, Ryan Quinn here from SymphonyOS.  We were dormant from our 2008.1 release until a couple months ago when we started on a new codebase.  The 2008.1 release does not use a full HTML interface but earlier releases do, though they are based on a very old version of Firefox.  We will be releasing a pre-alpha of Symphony Strata which will feature a brand new HTML5 based desktop environment designed for both local and remote use.  Unfortunately for quite a while our forums were not working properly (holding posts for moderation and not notifying me of those posts.  We didnt want to pre-moderate any comments and posts should show up properly now).  Right now the community remains quiet awaiting the pre-alpha release but I have now committed to at least two blog updates per week with notifications via facebook and twitter.

Symphony very seldom releases anything that is not given a pre-alpha, alpha, or beta label.  The reason for this is that the environment is ever evolving and we do not do code freezes for longer than it takes to get a release out the door.  The current Symphony Strata release is the first in our 3.x series of releases with 2008.1 being the only member of the 2.x series and 1.x series releases dating back to May, 2005.  We are not a dead project, just a small community who currently has our heads buried in the code pushing towards a new release.